# WCF service is not available access under HTTP (ERR_CONNECTION_RESET)

Tags: wcf, webhttpbinding

I have a WCF service (WebHttpBinding) running successfully.
I call it from browser like this:

```
http://xxxxx:9000/LicenseService/GetInterfaceVersion
```

Then browser displays:
"1.0"

The WCF service is running successfully for years, which is being accessed from different operating systems (Win7, Win10), including virtual machines.
However, service is not accessible from a **Windows Server 2022 virtual PC**. The error on the browser is ERR_CONNECTION_RESET.

I used Wireshark to monitor WCF server port. Here the result:

```
> 249   18.503053   from:wcf_client to:wcf_server   TCP 66  56249 → 9000 [SYN, ECN, CWR] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1340 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
> 250   18.503138   from:wcf_server to:wcf_client   TCP 66  9000 → 56249 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1360 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
> 257   18.731672   from:wcf_client to:wcf_server   TCP 60  56249 → 9000 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=1573632 Len=0
> 258   18.732173   from:wcf_client to:wcf_server   TCP 60  56249 → 9000 [RST, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=1573632 Len=0
```

The RST can be seen in the last line.

What can be the root cause of issue.
It is not SSL/TLS issue, because connection is HTTP.

Note: I enabled trace of WCF service. However, the client request is not visible in trace.

Thanks

Comment: Check firewall, VPN and TCP\IP Settings, and whether ports are occupied.